# как в джанго реализовать вид grid и list с помощью двух шаблонов

Tags: python, django

Нужно сделать чтобы пользователь мог выбирать вид сортировки как на сайте "aliexpress" list или grid, не могу разобраться как лучше всего это реализовать
[image: View.py]

```
def catalog(request, g='n', brands=None, body_type=None):
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    temp = ['catalog/catalog_list.html' if g == 'n' else 'catalog/catalog_grid.html']
    context = {'cars': cars}
    return render(request, temp, context)
```

[image: url.py]

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', catalog, name='catalog'),
    path('<slug:g>/', catalog, name='catalog_grid'),]
```

[image: Файлы templates]

[image: catalog_list.html]
[image: catalog_grid.html]
                           `<div class="switch"> <a href="{% url 'catalog:catalog' y %}" class="table_view"></a> <span class="list_view"></span> </div>`

[image: то что должно получиться]

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)